# Transform Scala Future to Reactor Flux

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor, spring-reactor

I´m calling an API that return a `Future of Scala`, and I want to transform into `Reactor Flux` obviously without block and await for the response of the future. I´m trying to use EmitterProcessor, and it works fine when the future is success, but unfortunately it's not when the future have a Timeout.

Here the code

```
private Flux<D> transformFutureToFlux(Future<T> future) {
    EmitterProcessor<D> emitterProcessor = EmitterProcessor.create();
    future.onComplete(getOnCompleteFunction(emitterProcessor), defaultExecutionContext());
    return Flux.from(emitterProcessor);
}

private <D> OnComplete getOnCompleteFunction(EmitterProcessor<D> emitterProcessor) {
    return new OnComplete() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Throwable t, Object result) {
            if (t != null) {
                processError(t);
            } else {
                processSucceed(result);
            }
        }

        private void processSucceed(Object result) {
            if (result instanceof ConnectorErrorVO) {
                publishConnectorErrorException((ConnectorErrorVO) result);
            } else {
                publishGenericResponse(result);
            }
        }

        private void publishGenericResponse(Object result) {
            if (result instanceof List<?>) {
                Flux.fromIterable((List<D>) result).subscribe(emitterProcessor);
            } else {
                Flux.just((D) result).subscribe(emitterProcessor);
            }
        }

        private void publishConnectorErrorException(ConnectorErrorVO result) {
            ConnectorErrorVO connectorErrorVO = result;
            Flux<D> error = Flux.error(new ConnectorErrorException( String.valueOf(connectorErrorVO.getCode()), connectorErrorVO.getDescription(), connectorErrorVO.getError()));
            error.subscribe(emitterProcessor);
        }

        private void processError(Throwable t) {
            ConnectorManagerExecutor.logger.error(null, "Error and recovery from connector manager transaction", t);
            if (t instanceof AskTimeoutException) {
                Flux.<D>error(new ConnectorErrorException("407", "connector timeout", ConnectorError.TIMEOUT)).subscribe(emitterProcessor);
            } else {
                Flux.<D>error(new ConnectorErrorException("500", t.getMessage(), ConnectorError.GENERIC)).subscribe(emitterProcessor);
            }
        }
    };
```

What I´m trying to do is correct?, there's any better way to do it?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you return a `Future`, it means there is only 1 return, not a series/stream of return value.
You can convert to `Flux` if you want, but why not instead use a `Mono`?

Also, if you're using scala, try to use the *reactor-scala-extensions's* `SMono.fromFuture`

Check [SMonoTest](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-scala-extensions/blob/master/src/test/scala/reactor/core/scala/publisher/SMonoTest.scala#L102) for an example.

```
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    StepVerifier.create(SMono.fromFuture(Future[Long] {
      randomValue
    }))
      .expectNext(randomValue)
      .verifyComplete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Flux.create()`? Instead of using a processor, you register a future callback that calls the provided `Sink` methods. Eg. for the `List` case you'd iterate over the list and emit each value through the `sink.next(T)` method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Could you please can provide an example call?. It is more efficient in that way? They way I did is wrong?. Thanks again

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, could you please can provide a code example?